# eAccelerator vs APC

Tags: php

I know this topic has been beat to death but a lot of the things I read are from 2006 and a few years old.  Surely each must have some improvements since?

Anyways, which is faster and where can I find up-to-date benchmarks of both?  I know APC will be included in PHP 6 but isn't that because it's written by PHP?  eAccelerator from what I can find still seems to be a bit faster.

Also another question what's the best configuration I can have for php (not servers) to maximize performance?  (aka just installing eaccelerator vs eaccelerator + zend optimizer).  Also do unused php modules slow php down even if not being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more than 3 years, I've never seen eAccelerator used, while I've seen APC used several times.

Not sure it'll get included in PHP 6, actually -- that was said a long time ago, but I stopped hearing that after a while. *Still, not hard to install by yourself.*

If you look at the releases of both software :

- APC : http://pecl.php.net/package/APC
- eAccelerator : http://eaccelerator.net/

The first one **seems** to be more actively developped / maintained.

APC also has some quite well-known people in its team ;-)

On the other end, I don't recognize many names on eAccelerator's team.

Not sure it matters that much, but, generally, a known-name means someone who has a good reputation...

I'd also say APC is known to be used by some pretty big websites ; here again, it might only be reputation... But being able to say "facebook uses APC" helps when you want to convince your client he can install it safely...

About benchmarks, I have not seen any recent one -- and I follow [Planet-PHP](http://www.planet-php.net/), which aggregates many blogs related to PHP.

About the configuration question : well, the more useless stuff you do, the more you waste time for nothing, obviously.

Un-used modules probably don't make that much of a difference, though -- unless you have thousand of servers, maybe... But you probably don't have that many ? ;-)

A good configuration of both Apache + MySQL + php.ini might be more useful than removing modules... I think...